# Creating an IShellItem instance for a non-existent file

Tags: windows, winapi, com, windows-shell

How can I get an [IShellItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761144.aspx) object for a non-existent file (or directory)?

- [SHCreateItemFromParsingName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762134.aspx) and [SHCreateItemFromRelativeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762135.aspx) fail with 0x80070002 (file not found) and
- [ILCreateFromPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378420.aspx) returns a `NULL` pidl.

First I thought it might be impossible, but for example [IFileSaveDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775688.aspx) creates such an `IShellItem` for its result (if you specify a new file in the dialog).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is such a thing as a simple pidl and they can represent non-existent files. So I guess you want [SHSimpleIDListFromPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762254%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [SHCreateItemFromIDList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762133%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately a shell item created this way is not accepted as a target path by `IFileOperation`. The [linked QA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11902068/7571258) shows how to get this use case working.

Comment: @zett42 The simple ID list created here points to a file, not a directory. If you give it a path like `c:\foo\bar` and then chop off the last item with `ILRemoveLastID` then you should have a directory pidl to `c:\foo`. The method you linked to works as well and lets you add attributes like hidden etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, haven't tried it out though. I'm sticking with the `IBindCtx` solution, since `SHSimpleIDListFromPath()` is deprecated.