# Creating directories during a copy using IFileOperation

Tags: c#, com

Using Stephen Toub's IFileOperation wrapper for C# ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163304.aspx)), which has been working well until now. Now I am trying to do a copy to gather files from network locations, each network location into its own subdirectory.

`\\FOO\data` into `C:\gather\Foo_data`
`\\BAR\manage\current` into `C:\gather\bar\manage`

And so on. The problem is in `FileOperation.CopyItem`. It must be because the destination directory doesn't exist yet—`IFileOperation` will create it during the copy, right? I used the technique from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835350/creating-an-ishellitem-instance-for-a-non-existent-file) and changed Toub's `FileOperation.CreateShellItem` to this:

```
private static ComReleaser<IShellItem> CreateShellItem( string path )
{
    try
    {
        return new ComReleaser<IShellItem>( (IShellItem)SHCreateItemFromParsingName( path, null, ref _shellItemGuid ) );
    }
    catch ( FileNotFoundException )
    {
        IntPtr pidl = SHSimpleIDListFromPath( path );
        IShellItem isi = (IShellItem)SHCreateItemFromIDList( pidl, ref _shellItemGuid );
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem( pidl );
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( "Shell item: " + isi.GetDisplayName( SIGDN.DesktopAbsoluteParsing ) );
        return new ComReleaser<IShellItem>( isi );
    }
}
```

I stuck the `Debug.WriteLine` in there to check that it's working, and it seems to be working fine; it writes the path back out.

But `IFileOperation.CopyItem` throws an `ArgumentException`, and I can't figure out why. Am I not doing the "`IShellItem` for a nonexistent file" correctly? I suspect I need to get `SFGAO_FOLDER` in there, since I am trying to create an `IShellItem` for a nonexistent *directory*, not file, but how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a lot of Googling and coding experimentation this weekend (what a wild party weekend), I found a solution.

1. Write a COM-compatible class that implements `IFileSystemBindData`.
2. Allocate a `WIN32_FIND_DATA` structure and set its `dwFileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`. (The other members are irrelevant here, as far as I can tell after some testing.)
3. Create an instance of your `IFileSystemBindData` class.
4. Pass your `WIN32_FIND_DATA` object to `IFileSystemBindData::SetFindData`.
5. Create an instance of `IBindCtx`.
6. Call its `IBindCtx::RegisterObjectParam` with arguments of `STR_FILE_SYS_BIND_DATA` (`#define`d as `L"File System Bind Data"`) and your `IFileSystemBindData` object.
7. Call `SHCreateItemFromParsingName` with the pathname of the directory to create, and your `IBindCtx` object.

It works. The binding-context object tells `SHCreateItemFromParsingName` not to query the filesystem, and just use what it's given. I got `IFileOperation` to copy a file into the new and cleverly-named directory `D:\Some\Path\That\Did\Not\Previously\Exist`, and it created all seven directories along the way. Presumably this same technique could be used to create an `IShellItem` for any non-existent filesystem object, depending on what you put in `dwFileAttributes`.

But it's ugly. I hope there's a better way. My coding experimentation was in C++; now to write the COM interop stuff to do it again in C#. Or maybe it will be easier to throw out the project and start over in C++.

Comment: [Windows classic sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appplatform/ParsingWithParameters/ParsingWithParameters.cpp) shows how to implement `IFileSystemBindData`.