# IFileSystemBindData implementation not fully working

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winapi

I'm using the IFileOperation (Windows shell) API to bulk copy/delete files.  So far all good. However, it's a little more complicated to copy/move files to a destination that doesn't exist yet - you need to create a shell item for the destination using the IFileSystemBindData interface.  It works - intermittently. Other times it throws an exception in the IfileOperation.MoveItem method.

Any advice welcomed.

Notes:

- The bound WIN_32_FIND_DATA appears corrupt in the SetFindData
  function where it is called in the bound context
- This thread was useful,
  and where I got my original information:
  [Creating directories during a copy using IFileOperation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902068/creating-directories-during-a-copy-using-ifileoperation)

Interface:

```
Namespace Shell
<ComImport> _
<Guid("01E18D10-4D8B-11d2-855D-006008059367")> _
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)> _
Public Interface IFileSystemBindData
    Function GetFindData(ByRef wfd As WIN32_FIND_DATA) As UInteger
    Function SetFindData(ByRef wfd As WIN32_FIND_DATA) As UInteger
End Interface

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Public Structure WIN32_FIND_DATA
    Public dwFileAttributes As UInteger
    Public ftCreationTime As System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME
    Public ftLastAccessTime As System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME
    Public ftLastWriteTime As System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME
    Public nFileSizeHigh As UInteger
    Public nFileSizeLow As UInteger
    Public dwReserved0 As UInteger
    Public dwReserved1 As UInteger
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=260)> Public cFileName As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=14)> Public cAlternateFileName As String
End Structure
End Namespace
```

Implementation:

```
Namespace Shell
Public Class FileSystemBindData
    Implements IFileSystemBindData

Dim wf As WIN32_FIND_DATA

    Public Function GetFindData(ByRef pfd As WIN32_FIND_DATA) As UInteger Implements IFileSystemBindData.GetFindData
        pfd = wf
        Return 0
    End Function

    Public Function SetFindData(ByVal pfd As WIN32_FIND_DATA) As UInteger Implements IFileSystemBindData.SetFindData
        wf = pfd
        Return 0
    End Function

    <DllImport("ole32.dll")> _
    Public Shared Function CreateBindCtx(reserved As UInteger, ByRef ppbc As IBindCtx) As Integer
    End Function
End Class
End Namespace
```

Creating the bind context:

```
Dim wfd As New WIN32_FIND_DATA
wfd.dwFileAttributes = &H10 'FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY'
fsbd.SetFindData(wfd)
Const STR_FILE_SYS_BIND_DATA As String = "File System Bind Data"
FileSystemBindData.CreateBindCtx(0, bc)
bc.RegisterObjectParam(STR_FILE_SYS_BIND_DATA, fsbd)
```

Function for Creating the shell item with destination and bind context-

```
Private Function CreateShellItemNew(destination As String) As ComReleaser(Of IShellItem)
Return New ComReleaser(Of IShellItem)(DirectCast(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(destination, bc, _shellItemGuid), IShellItem))
 End Function
```

Function called here. it throws on the MoveItem line "Value does not fall within the expected range"

```
Public Sub MoveItemCreateDest(source As String, destination As String, newName As String)
ThrowIfDisposed()
Try
    Using sourceItem As ComReleaser(Of IShellItem) = CreateShellItem(source)
        Using destinationItem As ComReleaser(Of IShellItem) = CreateShellItemNew(destination)
            _fileOperation.MoveItem(sourceItem.Item, destinationItem.Item, newName, Nothing)
        End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Moveitem error: " & ex.Message)
End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: The member functions of your `FileSystemBindData` class don't seem to do anything. You need to store the `WIN32_FIND_DATA` passed in to `SetFindData` and return it in `GetFindData`.

Comment: Thanks. Aren't the functions in FileSystemBindData just passing on the values to the Interface? Also, I don't think GetFindData is used. The SetFindData function stores the WIN32_FIND_DATA item which then is used by RegisterObjectParam. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: How do you think they pass it on exactly? Osmosis?

Comment: Hmmm - OK maybe I'm implementing this Interface the wrong way.  I think instead of the class inheriting IFileSystemBindData it should activate an _IFileSystemBindData object and pass via that.  Now I just have to work out how to get a type for the interface to pass to Activator!

Comment: Scratch my last comment, I've updated it above to get and set the value as suggested.  It is still throwing the exception though, though not always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it - flip the order of the functions the other way in the Interface and they are called correctly. Previously data corruption was occurring due to the functions being reversed (Set called instead of Get). I wasn't aware that the order of functions in a COM interface had an effect.

```
 <ComImport()> _
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)> _
<Guid("01E18D10-4D8B-11d2-855D-006008059367")> _
Public Interface IFileSystemBindData
    <PreserveSig()> Function SetFindData(ByVal pfd As WIN32_FIND_DATA) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Error)> Integer
    <PreserveSig()> Function GetFindData(<Out()> ByRef pfd As WIN32_FIND_DATA) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Error)> Integer
End Interface
```